# How do i pass the credentials of a service to its called Powershell script without explicitly passing the username + password?

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, powershell-2.0

The service (Jenkins) is running on a server as a different user account with additional permissions. It then calls a powershell script during a build to use those permissions (access to some folders on another server) but it doesn't work. In the script i've got the following code:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root '\\XXX\ctv$'
Get-Childitem -Path 'Y:\'
```

The result is:

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path '\\XXX\ctv$' is denied.
At D:\XXX\copy.ps1:2 char:14
+ get-childitem <<<<  -Path 'Y:\'
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\XXX\ctv$\:String 
   ) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Trying to access the folder directly returns a similar error, that the path was not found:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\XXX\ctv$\X\X'
```

I've also checked as which user the script is running as with

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
```

and it returned this

```
AuthenticationType : Negotiate
ImpersonationLevel : None
IsAuthenticated    : True
IsGuest            : False
IsSystem           : True
IsAnonymous        : False
Name               : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Owner              : S-1-5-32-544
User               : S-1-5-18
Groups             : {S-1-5-32-544, S-1-1-0, S-1-5-11}
Token              : 1072
```

which isn't the user Jenkins is running as.

So my question is how do i pass my script the same user that Jenkins is running as? Last resort would be to directly pass the username+password as credentials to the script but i would prefer if there is another way.

Comment: the problem probably lies in how you call powershell, not in the script itself. you could store the password of the user in a file (encrypted) if you want to specify the credentials in the script (See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx)

Comment: The solution to your problem is just as Paul described. You would need to create a credential as an encrypted string. Furthermore, the user (jenkins) must be the one to create the credential, and it can only be used on the machine that it was created on.